# Sizing the Header Apart From the Content

Tags: html, css

In my document, I have a header atop the page with a width of 3000px for differently scaled monitors, along with media below the header. 
I want the `body` to remain flexible to the user's page while still giving the same content every time (dynamic-static design). So, I have sized the header to proper proportions for every screen, but I still need the rest of the content to be 90%.

The problem is that if I give the `body` no width, and I put all of the content besides the header inside of wrapper styled with `width:90%`, I receive more of a right padding.

Check out the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/33bqj/3/

**In short**: I want everything BUT the header to have a width of 90%, but adding a wrapper around the content below the wrapper does not function properly. How can I get it to center, functioning like `body { width: 90% }`? CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
header {
    padding:0 20px;
    min-width:950px;
    min-height:115px;
    background:#FF6083 url(http://i.imgur.com/qsH5lTA.png) no-repeat center top;
}

.wrapper { 
    width:90%; 
    text-align:justify
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add margin left & right to wrapper class:

```
.wrapper { 
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:90%; 
    text-align:justify
}
```